# XMLHttpRequest state 2 waits for response from server

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to execute a block of code when my XMLHttpRequest reaches  state 2. The reason why I want it to be in state 2 is that I don't want the user to wait for a response of the server( I would like to redirect the user at this point).

```
    var xmlhttp;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else {// code for IE6, IE5
       xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {  
     if (xmlhttp.readyState == 2) {
        window.location.href = urlFromPreviousAjaxcall;
      }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "url", true);
    xmlhttp.send();
```

However the block of code inside the if(xmlhttp.readyState == 2) will only be called as soon as the server is done processing the call. This part has to be executed as soon as the call is made( without the waiting from the server).

In the documentation I found that state 2 is reached as soon as the call is send. However that is not the case.

---

Update:

the call I am trying to make involves calling a Api on the server( this takes time to complete). For the client it doesn't matter what happens to the call.The only thing I want is that the call is executed. So basicly I'm trying to gain speed here.

I know that as soon as I redirect the user, the code will stop running. However the call to the server should have been made(and send away).

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Keep in mind that when you unload the page any open connections will be aborted, this means your unfinished AJAX call will also be aborted, this seems very strange, why would you make an AJAX call and then intentionally not wait for it to complete?

Comment: @FritsvanCampen the call I am trying to make involves calling a Api on the server( this takes time to complete). For the client it doesn't matter what happens to the call.The only thing I want is that the call is executed. So basicly I'm trying to gain speed here.

Comment: Why not change the server side program so it sets the long running process going, then immediately returns a `204 No Content` response?

Comment: @Quentin I have tried such a thing, however i coudn't get that to work. Could you provide me with a code sample( in c#). I would really appreciate that!

Comment: I've spent about three hours playing with C# (mostly being confused by the different versions of .NET) … so no. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you all for your help.

I found the solution:

```
[HttpPost]
public void methode(String parameter,String parameter)
    {           
        Task.Factory.StartNew<string>(() => RunTask(accessToken, parameter, parameter));            
    }

private string RunTask(String parameter, String parameter)
    {
        try
        {
            // Code to execute here
            return "Done!";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return "Error: " + e.Message;
        }
    }
```

At the server I started a Task. In this task I execute the long procces. It still takes a brief moment before the server returns the call to the user.

When debuggin ( in visual studio) you can see that the task is running without the presents of the user.

Note : all sessions are gone at the moment I redirected the user to an other page.